# How to find layout position of footer within FlatList in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to find the y position of the component within a footer of a `FlatList`. I have tried calling the `onLayout` prop within the footer itself, however it only returns the co-ordinates of the component in question (`ComponentToFind`) relative to the parent component, which is the footer itself. How can I effectively call onLayout for this component and find its y-coordiante relative to the entire `FlatList` and not the footer itself?

```js
<FlatList<T>
                ref={flatListRef}
                onScroll={onScroll}
                scrollEventThrottle={160}
                ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
                ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
                ...
            />
```

```js
const renderFooter = useCallback(
        () => (
            <>
                <ComponentToFind
                    mt={3}
                    onLayout={(event) => {
                        const { y } = event.nativeEvent.layout
                        setFlatListHeight(y)
                    }}
                />
                <View />
                <View />
                <View />
                <View />
            </>
        ),
        [...]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use this solution:

```
const ref = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    ref.current.measure((fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
      console.log({fx, fy, width, height, px, py});
    });
  }, 1000);
  return () => {
     clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}, []);

const renderFooter = useCallback(
        () => (
            <>
                <View
                    ref={ref}
                />
                <View />
                <View />
                <View />
                <View />
            </>
        ),
        [...]
   )
```

The `py` value is what you find.

A litle time-out make sure the `ref` have value before performing measurement.

Comment: hi, im using py to scrollToOffset to the first item in my footer component but it's scrolling towards the end instead. how do i scroll to my footer component?